# Angular 2 - Extremely strange behaviour - changes appearing in one tab from another

Tags: javascript, angular

so I am an Angular 2 beginner and developing a simple CRUD application with authentication. Currently I have completed just a basic login form which submits uid/password to a NodeJS backend using an Angular service using an ngForm and then displays the authenticated components using `CanActivate` guard.

However, to much of my amazement, when I open the login form separately in 2 tabs and type something in the inputs, the text box in other tab gets updated automatically!

Even more strange, I asked a colleague to view the URL on his machine and, the changes he does in the inputs are reflected at my end! I have no clue as to how this could happen. I am using the default Angular lite server for development purposes. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out this is because of the `lite-server` and the `BrowserSync` plugin that Angular 2 dev environment has by default.
It tries to sync the input changes/clicks between browser tabs. To disable this, you can visit `http://<app url>:<app port+1>` and configure the plugin through UI.

For example if your app runs on 2000 port, you can configure the BrowserSync plugin using the same URL, but port 2001.